# Maintain user data in MEAN(Angular 2+)

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I using this project:  **https://github.com/DavideViolante/Angular-Full-Stack**
(MEAN,Angular 2+)
Here the cat data is visible to all. Which means If I login, I can see my friend's cat data and vice versa. How can I maintain separate data for each and every users?

Comment: attach a user id to cat obj when saved in the database and query against the current logged user id instead of asking for all cat data in the database.

Comment: Bro, You mean Mongoose populate?

Comment: @Chris what he mean is if you want to insert cat record in your database(mongodb or mysql) you need to specify the owner of the cat, then in your list just filter those cats whose owner is the currently logged user.

Comment: Ya i got it. Can you specify any link for reference?